# Vlc keeps automuting after system update

Tags: sound, updates, 22.04, vlc

I just made an update on Ubuntu 22.04 and the vlc now keeps automating. this happens randomly and sometimes when any other sound alert occurs such as notifications. At times it even pauses itself. This is very frustrating since my job involves a lot of notification alerts in a minute so I have to unmute or press play again every few seconds.
[image]

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?
Is there a way to remove the update I just made?

```
   Start-Date: 2023-05-10  18:23:59
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.137'
Install: linux-image-5.19.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-41.42~22.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.19.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-41.42~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.19.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-41.42~22.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-41:amd64 (5.19.0-41.42~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-41.42~22.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-71:amd64 (5.15.0-71.78, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-71-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-71.78, automatic)
Upgrade: libglib2.0-dev-bin:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu1, 2.72.4-0ubuntu2), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.70.68, 5.15.0.71.69), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (112.0.5615.165-1, 113.0.5672.92-1), libglib2.0-bin:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu1, 2.72.4-0ubuntu2), tzdata:amd64 (2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0, 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), linux-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.15.0.70.68, 5.15.0.71.69), linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (5.19.0.40.41~22.04.13, 5.19.0.41.42~22.04.14), libfreetype6:amd64 (2.11.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1, 2.11.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2), libfreetype6:i386 (2.11.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1, 2.11.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libglib2.0-data:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu1, 2.72.4-0ubuntu2), libssl3:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9), libssl3:i386 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9), ipp-usb:amd64 (0.9.20-1, 0.9.20-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (5.19.0.40.41~22.04.13, 5.19.0.41.42~22.04.14), linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (5.19.0.40.41~22.04.13, 5.19.0.41.42~22.04.14), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), distro-info-data:amd64 (0.52ubuntu0.3, 0.52ubuntu0.4), libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu1, 2.72.4-0ubuntu2), libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.72.4-0ubuntu1, 2.72.4-0ubuntu2), teamviewer:amd64 (15.40.8, 15.41.7), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), openssl:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-70.77, 5.15.0-71.78)
Remove: linux-headers-5.15.0-70:amd64 (5.15.0-70.77), linux-headers-5.15.0-70-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-70.77)
End-Date: 2023-05-10  18:28:14

Start-Date: 2023-05-10  18:28:36
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.137'
Remove: linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1), linux-headers-5.19.0-35-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1), linux-modules-5.19.0-35-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1), linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-35:amd64 (5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1), linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-35-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2023-05-10  18:29:09

Start-Date: 2023-05-10  18:38:46
Commandline: packagekit role='install-files'
Requested-By: kago (1000)
Install: qttranslations5-l10n:amd64 (5.15.3-1, automatic), libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), libqt5x11extras5:amd64 (5.15.3-1, automatic), libqt5network5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), libqt5dbus5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), libsdl-ttf2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.11-6, automatic), libdouble-conversion3:amd64 (3.1.7-4, automatic), libqt5widgets5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), libqt5gui5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), libpcre2-16-0:amd64 (10.39-3ubuntu0.1, automatic), libqt5printsupport5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), libqt5xml5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), libqt5opengl5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), libqt5sql5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), libqt5svg5:amd64 (5.15.3-1, automatic), libsdl1.2debian:amd64 (1.2.15+dfsg2-6, automatic), libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), virtualbox-7.0:amd64 (7.0.8-156879~Ubuntu~jammy), libmd4c0:amd64 (0.4.8-1, automatic), libxcb-xinput0:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu3, automatic), libqt5help5:amd64 (5.15.3-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2023-05-10  18:41:34

Start-Date: 2023-05-10  20:37:08
Commandline: apt install pavucontrol
Requested-By: kago (1000)
Install: pavucontrol:amd64 (5.0-2)
End-Date: 2023-05-10  20:37:16
```

enter code here

I also noticed that Rhythmbox behaves the same way. Whenever a new song starts it is muted. but not in rhythmbox but in the system settings.
To clarify I have teamviewer turned on most of the time. I'm controlling another device  but I'm not on call with them. Is this affecting the media players?
I have been using teamviewer for a couple of months without this issue. It just started after the update.

Comment: You've not said what *update* you're referring to, for us to advice on that you'd have to be specific (*we also don't know how often you perform upgrades, what mirror if any you're using etc so please be specific*). If your machine is using wireless keyboard; I'd check for RF interference with your machine receiving a command believed to be *mute* but from another device (*EMF meters can show what is causing this; RF can come from any old electrical device being used within 5-9 metres usually,, with patterns hard to easily or quickly determine*). What package(s) did you just update?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not very experienced with ubuntu. I receive a prompt with the update and just proceed to update without checking. Is there any way to find information on the updates made?

Comment: Hello again. I found the file and added the screenshot in the initial post at the post. I don't know if it will be helpful.

Comment: Ooh. sorry. Copy pasting...Done

Comment: Hello. Do you have an idea of what might be the problem?

Comment: I also noticed that Rhythmbox behaves the same way. Whenever a new song starts it is muted. but not in rhythmbox but in the system settings. To clarify I have teamviewer turned on most of the time. I'm controlling another device but I'm not on call with them. Is this affecting the media players? I have been using teamviewer for a couple of months without this issue. It just started after the update.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Teamviewer!! I uninstalled and everything Is working great right now.

Comment: Thank you for responding 